# Does CTRL + C cancels PHP script execution on Windows(WAMP)?

Tags: php, windows, console, console-application, windows-console

I created a script which checks every 10 seconds if our site is reachable again. If I now do this in the Powershell or Windows command line with

```
php test.php
```

and then end with CTRL + C, will the PHP execution be terminated in the background or will the script continue to run until the while condition no longer applies and the script comes to an end? The fact that no further output is visible in the console does not necessarily mean that the script execution was interrupted.

Thank you very much!

Comment: ctrl+c will cancel/kill it.. but go ahead an open the monitor and check.

Comment: What is `STRG`?

Comment: Unless the script spawns background processes, Ctl-c should kill it all, just like any other command.

Comment: Sry STRG german for CTRL :)

Comment: php.exe is a console executable. (php-win.exe is the GUI executable.) By default it does not install a C `SIGINT` handler, so Ctrl+C uses the default control handler that calls `ExitProcess`. Ctrl+C can be disabled via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` -- however that's called in PHP -- or by creating a new process group with the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` creation flag. CMD does the latter for the `/b` option of its `start` command, e.g. `start /b /w php test.php`. Either way, you can still use Ctrl+Break to exit the application.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with a logging script and after pressing CTRL + C no more log entries appeared. Is this behavior identical for Linux?

Comment: this is something you can easily test.